# Comparing two Excel files in R and returning different titles

Tags: r

I am working on a project at work where I am required to compare two Excel spreadsheets to see if a **title** has been added or removed from the second excel sheet (Book 2). The code I have created works well, however, it is difficult to interpret for someone without R experience and does not look great.

My goal is to compare two Excel spreadsheets and output the differences in a clear fashion so that my colleagues can understand and change the differences. Optimally, it would output a table that presents the information in a way that it can be easily located and changed. I appreciate all the help.

```
structure(list(Title = c("D", "Mortal Kombat", "Godzilla",
"Wonder", "Suicide Squad", "Mulan"), Studio = c("X", "X",
"X", "X", "X", "Y"), Type = c("Special", "Special", "Special",
"Special", "Special", "Special")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl",
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))


structure(list(Title = c("D", "Mortal Kombat", "Godzilla",
"Wonder", "Trolls"), Studio = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X"
), Type = c("Special", "Special", "Special", "Special", "Special"
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,
-5L))

library("compareDF")
library("readxl")

dat <- read_xlsx("Book1.xlsx")
dat2 <- read_xlsx("Book2.xlsx")


compare_df(dat, dat2)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly not elegant, but it should be functional with a readable output:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- read_xlsx("Book1.xlsx")
dat2 <- read_xlsx("Book2.xlsx")

book1_output <- anti_join(dat,dat2, by = "Title") %>% mutate(source = "Book1")
book2_output <- anti_join(dat2,dat, by = "Title") %>% mutate(source = "Book2")

final_output <- rbind(book1_output,book2_output)
```